# Running files from within project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project where I'm trying to run a batch file from within a class

The ultimate goal is to run this on many machines - so I can't use a "magic" path to use this file because it's located within my project not my C drive

The absolute path works (obviously), but I'm struggling to create a path within Eclipse to reference it

I have the batch.bat within a folder called "batchfiles" but when I try to run the following command I get a file not found error

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start \\batchfiles\\batch.bat");
```

even though batch.bat exists in that folder within my project

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look to **[ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)**. Here's a complete example from documentation :

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");
 Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
 env.put("VAR1", "myValue");
 env.remove("OTHERVAR");
 env.put("VAR2", env.get("VAR1") + "suffix");
 pb.directory(new File("myDir"));
 File log = new File("log");
 pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
 pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.appendTo(log));
 Process p = pb.start();
 assert pb.redirectInput() == Redirect.PIPE;
 assert pb.redirectOutput().file() == log;
 assert p.getInputStream().read() == -1;
```

In your case, I think the command should be :

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "start", "\\batchfiles\\batch.bat");
```